# C言語で偶数目の文字を表示する

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int len, i;
    char ch[] = "today";
    len = strlen(ch);

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            printf("%s\n", ch[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

といったプログラムを作りました。
これを実行すると偶数目であるoとaが表示されると思ったのですが、表示されません。
なぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ch[i]` は文字ですので、`printf` の書式文字列には `%c` を指定します。(なお、"o" と "a" を表示したい場合は、条件を少し変更する必要があります。)

Answer (score 7):

i が 0 から始まっているからです。
以下の様な条件にすると期待する動きになります。

```
if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
```

あと、printf文は %c を使うよう、修正する必要があります。

```
printf("%c\n", ch[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

~/test cat tst11.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str= "today";
    //
    for( int i= 0; *str; i++ ){
        if(( i & 1 ) != 0){
            putchar(*str);
        }
        str++;
    }
    //
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

~/test ./a.out
oa
~/test

Answer (score 0):

配列の添え字は0から始まります。

```
ch[0] : t
ch[1] : o
ch[2] : d
ch[3] : a
ch[4] : y
```

です。